# Repeat Delivery schedule calendar on magento cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need help regarding to magento cart page . I need a checkbox on cart page in product summary where user can select date when he wants to repeat order for a specific product.I am unable to add screenshot due to low reputation .

I need to solve this problem as soon as possible .Do let me know if anyone have information about related extension or any customization that i can do to solve this .

Comment: i can provide hint as following simple layout for products summary on cart page 
Product short description      edit       Repeat order       Qty       Total

Comment: Under repeat delivery there will be check box to on which calendar should be open to select date for repeating order